# UIButton resizing to fit text length

Tags: xcode, uibutton

There are a number of posts on Stack about this subject but I can't get any to work.

I have a Button whose text literal is supplied by a variable which can change in length. I want the button to be sufficiently long so the text is readable rather than concatenated in the middle with ".....".

If I use something like

```
CGSize stringsize = [myString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
NSLog(@"Width = %f", stringsize.width);
[myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20,0,stringsize.width, stringsize.height)];
```

Similarly I have been unable to get commands like to work either.

```
[self myButton sizeToFit];
```

Does anyone have a solution that does work?

I am trying to implement these from viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a storyboard? If so, go to your file inspector in the storyboard and see if you have "use autolayout" checked. From what I can tell, uibuttons won't respond to frame changes while this option is checked.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for Xcode 7.2**

Click on the view that needs the fit
(Not from the list of views from the left panel, but in the stage itself)

Now click on `Editor` menu, and then `Size to Fit Content`

**Voila!!**

*You can use the shortcut* `command` + `=`